# What are the differences between C, C# and C++ in terms of real-world applications?

Tags: c#, c++, c, comparison

As I posted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388156/what-web-oriented-language-should-i-learn-after-php) I've decided to try my hand at one of these, but given my interests as a web developer, I'd like to know the difference between them in their real-world applications.

**Edit Note:**

While I'm a web developer, please don't let that limit your answer. I'm 30...I've got years of career changing ahead of me.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're interested in a comparison from a web-application perspective?

Comment: Do you want to remain a web developer, or are you looking to do something different? e.g. iPhone apps programming language is largely based on Objective-C

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Both C and C++ give you a lower level of abstraction that, with increased complexity, provides a breadth of access to underlying machine functionality that are not necessarily exposed with other languages. Compared to C, C++ adds the convenience of a fully object oriented language(reduced development time) which can, potentially, add an additional performance cost.  In terms of real world applications, I see these languages applied in the following domains:

C

- Kernel level software.
- Hardware device drivers
- Applications where access to old, stable code is required.

C,C++

- Application or Server development where memory management needs to be fine tuned (and can't be left to generic garbage collection solutions).
- Development environments that require access to libraries that do not interface well with more modern managed languages.
- Although managed C++ can be used to access the .NET framework, it is not a seamless transition.

C# provides a managed memory model that adds a higher level of abstraction again.  This level of abstraction adds convenience and improves development times, but complicates access to lower level APIs and makes specialized performance requirements problematic.

It is certainly possible to implement extremely high performance software in a managed memory environment, but awareness of the implications is essential.

The syntax of C# is certainly less demanding (and error prone) than C/C++ and has, for the initiated programmer, a shallower learning curve.

C#

- Rapid client application development.
- High performance Server development (StackOverflow for example) that benefits from the .NET framework.
- Applications that require the benefits of the .NET framework in the language it was designed for.

[Johannes Rössel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/johannes-r246ssel) makes the valid point that the use C# Pointers, Unsafe and Unchecked keywords break through the layer of abstraction upon which C# is built. I would emphasize that type of programming is the exception to most C# development scenarios and not a fundamental part of the language (as is the case with C/C++).

Comment: You still have pretty good control over lower-level things in C# with keywords like unsafe and unchecked; you can even use pointers if you can't escape the C world :)

Comment: I guess my point is that that the lower level abstraction is part of the language with C.  Pointers, Unsafe and Unchecked are breaking out of C#' higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 78):

Bear in mind that I speak [ASFAC++B](http://www.earwicker.com/asfacppb.html). :) I've put the most important differentiating factor first.

**Garbage Collection**

Garbage Collection (GC) is the single most important factor in differentiating between these languages.

While C and C++ can be used with GC, it is a bolted-on afterthought and cannot be made to work as well ([the best known is here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)) - it has to be "conservative" which means that it cannot collect all unused memory.

C# is designed from the ground up to work on a GC platform, with standard libraries also designed that way. It makes an absolutely fundamental difference to developer productivity that has to be experienced to be believed.

There is a belief widespread among C/C++ users that GC equates with "bad performance". But this is out-of-date folklore (even the Boehm collector on C/C++ performs much better than most people expect it to). The typical fear is of "long pauses" where the program stops so the GC can do some work. But in reality these long pauses happen with non-GC programs, because they run on top of a virtual memory system, which occasionally interrupts to move data between physical memory and disk.

There is also widespread belief that GC can be replaced with [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), but it can't; the irony is that in a multi-threaded program, `shared_ptr` is slower than a GC-based system.

There are environments that are so frugal that GC isn't practical - but these are increasingly rare. Cell phones typically have GC. The CLR's GC that C# typically runs on appears to be state-of-the-art.

Since adopting C# about 18 months ago I've gone through several phases of pure performance tuning with a profiler, and the GC is so efficient that it is practically invisible during the operation of the program.

GC is not a panacea, it doesn't solve all programming problems, it only really cleans up memory allocation, if you're allocating very large memory blocks then you will still need to take some care, and it is still possible to have what amounts to a memory leak in a sufficiently complex program - and yet, the effect of GC on productivity makes it a pretty close approximation to a panacea!

**Undefined Behaviour**

C++ is founded on the notion of undefined behaviour. That is, the language specification defines the outcome of certain narrowly defined usages of language features, and describes all other usages as causing *undefined behaviour*, meaning in principle that the operation could have any outcome at all (in practice this means hard-to-diagnose bugs involving apparently non-deterministic corruption of data).

Almost everything about C++ touches on undefined behaviour. Even very nice forthcoming features like lambda expressions can easily be used as convenient way to corrupt the stack (capture a local by reference, allow the lambda instance to outlive the local).

C# is founded on the principle that all possible operations should have defined behaviour. The worst that can happen is an exception is thrown. This completely changes the experience of software construction.

(There's unsafe mode, which has pointers and therefore undefined behaviour, but that is strongly discouraged for general use - think of it as analogous to embedded assembly language.)

**Complexity**

In terms of complexity, C++ has to be singled out, especially if we consider the very-soon-to-be standardized new version. C++ does absolutely everything it can to make itself effective, short of assuming GC, and as a result it has an awesome learning curve. The language designers excuse much of this by saying "Those features are only for library authors, not ordinary users" - but to be truly effective in any language, you need to build your code as reusable libraries. So you can't escape.

On the positive side, C++ is so complex, it's like a playground for nerds! I can assure you that you would have a lot of fun learning how it all fits together. But I can't seriously recommend it as a basis for productive new work (oh, the wasted years...) on mainstream platforms.

C keeps the language simple (simple in the sense of "the compiler is easy to write"), but this makes the coding techniques more arcane.

Note that not all new language features equate with added complexity. Some language features are described as "syntactic sugar", because they are shorthand that the compiler expands for you. This is a good way to think of a great deal of the enhancements to C# over recent years. The language standard even specifies some features by giving the translation to longhand, e.g. `using` statement expands into `try`/`finally`.

At one point, it was possible to think of C++ templates in the same way. But they've since become so powerful that they are now form the basis of a whole separate dimension of the language, with its own [enthusiastic user communities and idioms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html).

**Libraries**

The strangest thing about C and C++ is that they don't have a standard interchangeable form of pre-compiled library. Integrating someone else's code into your project is always a little fiddly, with obscure decisions to be made about how you'll be linking to it.

Also, the standard library is extremely basic - C++ has a complete set of data structures and a way of representing strings (`std::string`), but that's still minimal. Is there a standard way of finding a list of files in a directory? Amazingly, no! Is there standard library support for parsing or generating XML? No. What about accessing databases? Be serious! Writing a web site back-end? Are you crazy? etc.

So you have to go hunting further afield. For XML, try [Xerces](http://projects.apache.org/projects/xerces_c++_xml_parser.html). But does it use `std::string` to represent strings? Of course not!

And do all these third-party libraries have their own bizarre customs for naming classes and functions? You betcha!

The situation in C# couldn't be more different; the fundamentals were in place from the start, so everything inter-operates beautifully (and because the fundamentals are supplied by the CLR, there is cross-language support).

It's not all perfect; generics should have been in place from the start but wasn't, which does leave a visible scar on some older libraries; but it is usually trivial to fix this externally. Also a number of popular libraries are ported from Java, which isn't as good a fit as it first appears.

**Closures (Anonymous Methods with Local Variable Capture)**

Java and C are practically the last remaining mainstream languages to lack closures, and libraries can be designed and used much more neatly with them than without (this is one reason why ported Java libraries sometimes seem clunky to a C# user).

The amusing thing about C++ is that its standard library was designed as if closures were available in the language (container types, `<algorithm>`, `<functional>`). Then ten years went by, and now they're finally being added! They will have a huge impact (although, as noted above, they leak underfined behaviour).

C# and JavaScript are the most widely used languages in which closures are "idiomatically established". (The major difference between those languages being that C# is statically typed while JavaScript is dynamically typed).

**Platform Support**

I've put this last only because it doesn't appear to differentiate these languages as much as you might think. All these languages can run on multiple OSes and machine architectures. C is the most widely-supported, then C++, and finally C# (although C# can be used on most major platforms thanks to an open source implementation called [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)).

My experience of porting C++ programs between Windows and various Unix flavours was unpleasant. I've never tried porting anything very complex in C# to Mono, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially the part about undefined behavior and the problem with libraries. These two things cause so much trouble in the C++ world, yet sometimes beginners see them as an advantage and defend them.

Comment: (0) C# is not way cross platform, forget about it. (1) Mono is now way to make C# "cross platform" as it is far behind .Net. (2) C# Lacks of one important thing RAII (and no, using does not replace it). (3) There is one huge undefined-non-deterministic behavior in C# called GC. (4) About libraries... there is enough toolkits to do all tasks you want... But yes, there is more then one such... It is question of choise.

Comment: @Artyom - mono is up to date with C# 3.0, and already working on 4.0 before it's released. Lots of real projects are using it. Novell is investing in it. IDisposable/using _precisely_ and _exactly_ replaces RAII - if you don't understand that then you probably don't understand RAII itself. Same goes for thinking GC is undefined, you apparently don't know what undefined means either.

Comment: I believe what he means is "non-deterministic," which is precisely what GC is.  And the CLR's generational garbage collector can be considered undefined behavior in the sense that you have no defined guarantee that any given object that lives past generation 1 will ever actually be collected before the app terminates.

Comment: That's true - but then any multi-threaded programming will also be non-deterministic. And the fact that the GC may not collect all objects is undetectable as long as they have no finalizer; almost all most applications of finalizers are nowadays replaced by SafeHandle, which is guaranteed to be cleaned up during termination. A far more obvious target for claims of undefined behaviour in C# is unsafe blocks - but they are like a rarely used embedded DSL, similar to an assembly language block in C++.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker - Are you still developing in C# as your language of choice today?

Comment: @Aidenhjj yes, though only at work where it's a very common corporate choice. On home projects I tend to prefer TypeScript either on Node or the browser.

Answer (score 15):

C is the bare-bones, simple, clean language that makes you do everything yourself.  It doesn't hold your hand, it doesn't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.  But it has everything you need to do what you want.

C++ is C with classes added, and then a whole bunch of other things, and then some more stuff.  It doesn't hold your hand, but it'll let you hold your own hand, with add-on GC, or RAII and smart-pointers.  If there's something you want to accomplish, chances are there's a way to abuse the template system to give you a relatively easy syntax for it. (moreso with C++0x).  This complexity also gives you the power to accidentally create a dozen instances of yourself and shoot them all in the foot.

C# is Microsoft's stab at improving on C++ and Java.  Tons of syntactical features, but no where near the complexity of C++.  It runs in a full managed environment, so memory management is done for you.  It does let you "get dirty" and use unsafe code if you need to, but it's not the default, and you have to do some work to shoot yourself.

Comment: Can you clarify "but no where near the complexity of C++"? It's hard to know if, by what you wrote, that's good or bad. I believe I know what you're getting at, but it's not clear.

Comment: It's neither good nor bad in my opinion, C# is easier to learn and doesn't have the dark corners of C++, but there is a reason behind every bit of complexity in C++.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is C# and ASP.NET would be the best of the three for development that is web biased.

I doubt anyone writes new web apps in C or C++ anymore. It was done 10 years ago, and there's likely a lot of legacy code still in use, but they're not particularly well suited, there doesn't appear to be as much (ongoing) tool support, and they probably have a small active community that does web development (except perhaps for web server development). I wrote many website C++ COM objects back in the day, but C# is far more productive that there's no compelling reason to code C or C++ (in this context) unless you need to.

I do still write C++ if necessary, but it's typically for a small problem domain. e.g. communicating from C# via P/Invoke to old C-style dll's - doing some things that are downright clumsy in C# were a breeze to create a C++ COM object as a bridge.

The nice thing with C# is that you can also easily transfer into writing Windows and Console apps and stay in C#. With Mono you're also not limited to Windows (although you may be limited to which libraries you use).

Anyways this is all from a web-biased perspective. If you asked about embedded devices I'd say C or C++. You could argue none of these are suited for web development, but C#/ASP.NET is pretty slick, it works well, there are heaps of online resources, a huge community, and free dev tools.

So from a real-world perspective, picking only one of C#, C++ and C as requested, as a general rule, you're better to stick with C#.

Answer (score 5):

C - an older programming language that is described as Hands-on. As the programmer you must tell the program to do everything. Also this language will let you do almost anything. It does not support object orriented code. Thus no classes.

C++ - an extention language per se of C. In C code ++ means increment 1. Thus C++ is better than C. It allows for highly controlled object orriented code. Once again a very hands on language that goes into MUCH detail.

C# - Full object orriented code resembling the style of C/C++ code. This is really closer to JAVA. C# is the latest version of the C style languages and is very good for developing web applications.

Comment: How different are they syntactically speaking?

Answer (score 4):

From your other posts, I guess you want to learn a new language to get new skills. My advice is that the language is not really important, what is important is the quality of its community (advice, but also existing code you can read and learn from) and the available libraries/frameworks. In this respect, I think the "C family" is not the best choice for you: web libraries and frameworks are few, not portable and not great, and coding style of code you can study varies a lot and may confuse you a lot (although C is my favorite language).

I would advise to just learn C, and try to really understand the concept of pointers, then move to other languages more adapted to the web ([Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) or [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) comes to mind - or even [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)). Also, in the C family, [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) has the best mix of power and simplicity in my opinion, but is a niche player.

Answer (score 1):

For raw speed, use C.  For power, use C++.  For .NET compatibility, use C#.

They're all pretty complex as languages go; C through decades of gradual accretion, C++ through years of more rapid enhancement, and C# through the power of Microsoft.

Comment: Eh, there are plenty of cases where C++ is faster than C (std::sort vs qsort is an obvious example). As http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx shows, C# generally performs just as well too. It takes a lot of work to get C/C++ to perform better than plain C# code.

Comment: The only point for C# you give is for ".net compatibility"? Come on now.

Comment: @jalf: sry, but your comment is like comparing apples, oranges and potatoes. C and C++ are roughly the same speed (excepting different code / libraries), while C# can probably never be as fast as the former.

Comment: @jcinacio, because of the jitter, .net code can be faster than c/C++, depending on the circumstances

Comment: I also like C++/CLI, it gives you the best of both worlds if you are doing .net programming, especially if you are an old C++ nerd like me.

Answer (score 1):

C is the core language that most closely resembles and directly translates into CPU machine code.  CPUs follow instructions that move, add, logically combine, compare, jump, push and pop.  C does exactly this using much easier syntax.  If you study the disassembly, you can learn to write C code that is just as fast and compact as assembly.  It is my preferred language on 8 bit micro controllers with limited memory.  If you write a large PC program in C you will get into trouble because of its limited organization.  That is where object oriented programming becomes powerful.  The ability of C++ and C# classes to contain data and functions together enforces organization which in turn allows more complex operability over C.  C++ was essential for quick processing in the past when CPUs only had one core.  I am beginning to learn C# now.  Its class only structure appears to enforce a higher degree of organization than C++ which should ultimately lead to faster development and promote code sharing.  C# is not interpreted like VB.  It is partially compiled at development time and then further translated at run time to become more platform friendly.