# Im getting error while trying to run program after used clean statement

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I have to write simple `makefile` program that combines three files: `mymath.h` `mymath.c` and `calc.c`,build static and shared library,link everything and in the end delete all unnecessary files

I have already finished my program,but when I try to run `./libshared` im getting error

```
all: lib_dyn_run lib_stat_run clean

lib_dyn_run: calc.c lib_dyn.so
        gcc calc.c -o libshared -L. lib_dyn.so
lib_dyn.so: mymathdyn.o calcdyn.o
        gcc -shared -o lib_dyn.so mymathdyn.o calcdyn.o
mymathdyn.o: mymath.c
        gcc -fPIC -c mymath.c -o mymathdyn.o
calcdyn.o: calc.c
        gcc -fPIC -c calc.c -o calcdyn.o
lib_stat_run: calc.c lib_stat.a
        gcc -o libstatic calc.c -L. lib_stat.a
lib_stat.a: mymath.o calc.o
        ar rcs lib_stat.a mymath.o calc.o
mymath.o: mymath.c mymath.h
        gcc -c mymath.c
calc.o: calc.c mymath.h
        gcc -c calc.c
clean:
        rm -f all *.o *.a *.so *.gch
```

When I run `./libstatic` everything is fine and im getting correct result

When I run `./libshared` im getting error

> error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

I know that problem is .so in "clean" function but how is that necessary file since it's build similarly to `lib_stat_run` that works fine.I want to remove all files except source files and two .exe files

Comment: [What are the differences between C, C# and C++ in terms of real-world application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692225/what-are-the-differences-between-c-c-sharp-and-c-in-terms-of-real-world-appli) you seem to be a little confused

Comment: The posted Makefile is missing several important (but not necessarily critical) details,  Details like: `.PHONY: all clean`

Comment: this part of the `clean` rule: `*.a *.so` is eliminating the static and dynamic libraries that the rest of the makefile just created

Comment: [What is the difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2649334/1362568)

Answer (score 0):

Your `clean` command is configured to delete `*.so` which are the Shared Object files that your libshared depends on.

Answer (score 0):

an executable, built with `static` contains the needed library functions within itself,  so it needs no external libraries.

However, a dynamic executable does NOT contain the functions from the external (*.so) libraries, only the prototypes, so the external libraries much be visible at run time.